# Remove Vim first column highlight

Tags: vim

Some how the first column of any vim buffer is being highlighted. I didn't notice until today so I'm not really sure when the change happened. I tried to mess around with the search options and highlighting options but I was not successful.

Does anybody have any idea to what may be causing this?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is my vimrc: https://tinyurl.com/mrbcu77

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you wrote your `vimrc` by yourself. If you search in that file for `colorcolumn`, you found two lines:

```
50:set colorcolumn=+1
```

and

```
70:set colorcolumn+=1
```

70 line, you force the 1st column to be highlighted.

remove that line and try again.

also you auto load (source) vimrc by autocmd when it was saved. you can try opening it in vim, and save it 10-20 times, see how slow your vim would be. You should clear autocmds before create them.

Comment: Ah must of missed the second one. Thanks